# OpenVPN тоннель

Tags: openvpn

Есть у меня сервер:

Внешний адрес: OUT_IP - выделенная линия провайдера

Внутренний IP: IN_IP - локалка

Выступает в качестве шлюза под виндос 2003. На сервер установил OpenVPN.

И есть клиент, находится в другой стране, выход в интернет 3G-modem. У него тоже есть OpenVPN. Соединяется к моему серверу через VPN-туннель.

Вопрос: Как настроить VPN соединение, чтобы весь интернет-траффик клиента уходил через тоннель? То есть, если он попытается открыть сайт, или поговорить в мессенджере, то соединение проходило через мой шлюз? IP клиента динамический.

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге openvpn сервера, пропишите push "redirect-gateway def1"

Answer (score 0):

Вам каким-то образом необходимо переназначить шлюз вашего клиента на IP-адрес VPN соединения. Полагаю, что есть некоторая настройка в OpenVPN клиенте.

В обычном соединении VPN в свойствах на вкладке "Сеть" выбрать "Протокол интернета TCP/IPv4" свойства, затем кнопка "Дополнительно...", где находите галочку "Использовать основной шлюз в удаленной сети".

Comment: в конфиге openvpn можно явные шлюзы назначать, но там предпологается физические айпишки, а у клиента, к сожалению, динамический...

Comment: А вы ему выдаете динамические IP?

Comment: Нет, но 3G-модем ведь дает ддинамические

Comment: Но вам шлюз по умолчанию нужен, который будет смотреть на ваш ВПН. А это АйПи, который дает ВПН-сервер вашему клиенту.Например, если у меня ВПН-сервер имеет адрес `172.16.224.1`, а клиент `172.16.224.2`, то шлюз по умолчанию будет именно адрес моего ВПН-клиента.

Answer (score 0):

как и предлагалось, **вариант 1:**

`push "redirect-gateway def1"` **в настройках сервера.** В этом случае **ВСЕ подключенные клиенты примут директиву перенаправления трафика через openvpn.**

Еслиже вы хотите подключаться так же и сами (например удаленно со смартфона) и при этом НЕ хотите, чтобы весь ваш трафик шел через vpn, то **вместо** этой строки в конфиге сервера, пропишите **вариант2:**

`redirect-gateway def1` **в настройках клиента.**